# Spinner Default Value / Change position

Tags: java, android

Hello to the community,

got a problem with the implementation of my project, which I hope someone can give me because some clarity.
Short description of my project:
I want to change from the Activity_A means of a button onclick events the default position of a spinner in the Activity_B. In my sample code I've tried using an Intent, Value Activity_A to the spinner in the Activity_B in an if - to give statement which then starts the spinner in the corresponding position.

Here is my code:

**Activity_A:**

```
public class Start extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.start);            

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, Spinnerwert.class);          
                intent.putExtra("position", "3");
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });    



        }

    }
```

**Activity_B:**

```
public class Spinnerwert extends Activity {


    private TextView beschreibung_1;
    private TextView beschreibung_2;

    private Spinner s1;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_wert);

        // TextView issue of Spinner
        beschreibung_1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV_spinner_1);  

        // TextView output Intent worth 
        beschreibung_2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV_spinner_2);


        // Intent data receiving
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String selected = i.getStringExtra("position");     
        beschreibung_2.setText(selected);       


        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,         R.array.auswahl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {



        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Spinner position - Response to Intent worth handover --------

            s1.setSelection(position);


            if (position == 0) {                    
                s1.setSelection(0);

            } else if (position == 1) {   
                s1.setSelection(1);

            } else if (position == 2) {    
                s1.setSelection(2); 

            }

        beschreibung_1.setText((CharSequence) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));  

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });  


    }

}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? Where? It's not really clear what the question is here.

Comment: Please clean up your code formatting. "Activity A" is particularly hard to follow with the bad indentation. Additionally, what exactly is your question? Are you getting error messages or bad results?

Comment: So have again reworked ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're never setting the spinner to the selected index.  Your if statements in onItemSelected aren't doing anything since "position" is a value that gets passed in from the spinner and not the previous intent.

Try putting this

```
s1.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(selected));
```

after you set your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response was exactly what had been missing. Did not think that it works the same with just one line of code works just as it should.
Have tried the whole again with Spinner (Value) and compare (equals) also works. (code shown below)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though your intent is passing a String extra, and only changing a text view within the second activity. If I am correct at understanding your question, you are wanting to place the spinner in a certain position based on the intent passed from the first activity.

Using the calls similar to those in your IF statement, simply parse the selected String to an int and call s1.setSelection on it.

It should look something like this:

```
    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,         R.array.auswahl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(selection));
```

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response was exactly what had been missing. Did not think that it works the same with just one line of code works just as it should.
Have tried the whole again with Spinner (Value) and compare (equals) also works. (code shown below)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Spinner variant with equals value

```
public class Spinnerwert_2 extends Activity {

    private TextView beschreibung_3;
    private TextView beschreibung_4;

    private Spinner s2;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_wert_2);


        beschreibung_3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV_spinner_3);
        beschreibung_4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV_spinner_4);


        Intent intent_spinner_2 = getIntent();       
        String spinner_2_auswahl = intent_spinner_2.getStringExtra("position_spinner_2");
        beschreibung_4.setText(spinner_2_auswahl);       


        // #2 Spinner + Funktion(Auswahl aus Resource values/array.xml)

        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.auswahl, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter_2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter_2);

        // #2 SPINNER-ITEM POSITIONSEINSTELLUNG / ZUWEISUNG  
        s2.setSelection(adapter_2.getPosition(spinner_2_auswahl));

        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if (s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Mercury")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auswahl Mercury", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                

            } else if (s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Venus")){                              

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auswahl Venus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (s2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Earth")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auswahl Earth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } 

        beschreibung_3.setText((CharSequence) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });  



    }

}
```